# Access elements in Struct by Address

Tags: c++, c, memory, struct

I've done some research and I cant quite find what I'm looking for on here or google. Is there a way to access the elements in a Customer by address (and not by using customer[i].bottles). I cannot modify the struct so I cannot put the properties into an array.

```
typedef struct Customer {
  int id;
  int bottles;
  int diapers;
  int rattles;
} Customer;

Customer customers[100];

void setValue(int custInd, int propertyInd) {
  //propertyInd would be 1 for id, 2 for bottles
  //Attempting to set customers[0].bottles
  *(&customers[custInd]+propertyInd) = 5;
}
```

I thought I'd be able to do this but I got various errors. Knowing that the "bottles" value will be the second space in memory from the address of a Customer shouldn't i be able to directly set the spot.

I know this may be improper code but I would like to understand how and why does/doesnt work. I also promise I have reasons for attempting to do this over the conventional way hah

Comment: This `*(&customers[custInd]+propertyInd) = 5` is basically the same as `customers[custInd+propertyInd] = 5`, why don't you just do `switch (propertyInd) { case 0: customers[custInd].id = 5; default: break'}`?

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `propertyInd`, perhaps pass an offset into the structure. That way, the code will work even if the layout changes dramatically (for example, if it includes non-int fields at the beginning).

Here's how you might do it:

```
void setValue(int custInd, int fieldOffset) {
    int *ptr = (int *)((char *)&customers[custInd] + fieldOffset);
    *ptr = 5;
}

...
setValue(custInd, offsetof(Customer, bottles));
```

`offsetof` is a standardized macro that returns the offset, in bytes, from the start of the structure to the given element.

If you still want to use indices, you can compute the offset as `propertyInd * sizeof(int)`, assuming every field in the struct is an `int`.

Comment: If you're willing to make the assumption made by the last paragraph, you could write, rather more simply, `((int*)&customers[custInd])[propertyInd] = 5`. But aiui, that assumption cannot be made in compliant C.

Comment: Thanks so much! this is great. Could you explain why we type cast to char and then to an int?

Comment: We typecast to `char *` so that we can add the offset, then typecast to `int *` so we have the right type of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
*(&customers[custInd]+propertyInd) = 5;
```

because the type of `&customers[custInd]`  is `struct Customer*`, not `int *`. So `&customers[custInd]+propertyInd` means the same thing as `&customers + custInd + propertyInd` or, in other words, `&customers[custInd + propertyInd]`. The assignment then attempts to set a structure value to the integer `5`, which is obviously illegal.

What I suppose you meant was

```
((int*)&customers[custInd])[propertyInd] = 5;
```

which would compile fine, and would probably work[*], but is undefined behaviour because you cannot assume that just because a struct consists of four `int`s, that it is laid-out in memory the same way as `int[4]` would be. It may seem reasonable and even logical that they layout be the same, but the standard doesn't require it, so that's that. Sorry.

As @iharob suggests in a comment, you might find a compiler clever enough to generate efficient code from the following verbiage:

```
void setValue(int custInd, int propertyInd, int value) {
  //propertyInd would be 1 for id, 2 for bottles
  switch (propertyInd) {
    case 1: customers[custInd].id = value; break;
    case 2: customers[custInd].bottles = value; break;
    case 3: customers[custInd].diapers = value; break;
    case 4: customers[custInd].rattles = value; break;
    default: assert(0);
  }
}
```

*: Actually, it would (probably) work if `propertyInd` for `id` were 0, not 1. C array indices start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

`&customers[custInd]` is a pointer to `customers[custInd]`, so `&customers[custInd]+propertyInd` is a pointer to `customers[custInd+propertyInd]`.   It is not a pointer to a member.  It will have type pointer to `Customer`.   The value of that pointer will be equal to `&(customers[custInd+propertyInd].id)`, but is not a pointer to int - hence the compiler error.

Your bigger problem is that four `int` in a struct are not necessarily laid out like an array of `int` - there may be padding between struct members.   So, if we do

```
int *p = &(customers[custInd].id);
```

then p+1 is not necessarily equal to `&(customers[custInd].bottles)`.

So you will need to do something like

```
void setValue(int custInd, int Offset)
{
    int *ptr = (int *)(((char *)&customers[custInd]) + Offset);
    *ptr = 5;
}

/*  and to call it to set customers[custInd].bottles to 5 */

setValue(custInd, offsetof(Customer, bottles));
```

Comment: I don't believe there will be padding between adjacent values of the same type in a struct, though I would like to be proven wrong on that.

Comment: For older processors that lack barrel shifters, such padding was necessary.

Comment: I don't see what barrel shifters have to do with this? I'm talking about padding between two values of the same type...